# How to convert javascript numeric date into C# date (using C#, not javascript!)

Tags: c#, javascript, datetime, date

I'm scraping a website and in the html it has a date in the following format:

```
"date":"\/Date(1184050800000-0700)\/"
```

If this was in javascript, it would be a date object and I could use its methods to retrieve the data in whatever format I like. However, I'm scraping it in a C# app. Does anyone know what this format is? Is it the total number of seconds after a certain date or something? I need a way to convert this to a C# datetime object.

Comment: How would yo do it in javascript?

Comment: Any example of the source would be really useful

Comment: Anyone coming to this question now should be using the built-in `DateTimeOffset.ToUnixTime*(..)` and `FromUnixTime*(...)` and possibly `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(..)` to handle timezone offset, [link to the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.fromunixtimeseconds?view=net-5.0#System_DateTimeOffset_FromUnixTimeSeconds_System_Int64_)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, **that is a Unix timestamp in milliseconds**. `1184050800000` is the timestamp itself, and `-0700` is the time zone. [This epoch convertor](http://www.epochconverter.com/) confirms.

Here is some code I've used before for converting Unix timestamps into DateTimes. Be sure to include only the part before `-0700`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Converts a Unix timestamp into a System.DateTime
/// </summary>
/// <param name="timestamp">The Unix timestamp in milliseconds to convert, as a double</param>
/// <returns>DateTime obtained through conversion</returns>
public static DateTime ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(double timestamp)
{
    DateTime origin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    return origin.AddSeconds(timestamp / 1000); // convert from milliseconds to seconds
}
```

If you encounter Unix timestamps that are in seconds, you just have to remove the `/ 1000` part of the last line of the code.

Comment: The correct answer. You could use the `AddMilliseconds` method rather than dividing by 1000, although it makes no difference whatsoever in this case

Comment: Does the timestamp take the offset into account, or is the string supposed to mean (timestamp + offset)? My answer uses the offset in its calculation...

Comment: @BoltClock I think it's based on UTC time. Thus, after you convert it into a DateTime, you're going to have to express the offset using DateTime functionality.

Answer (score 1):

As sinelaw says it seems to be a regex of some sort, however I tried parsing out the numeric values:

```
1184050800000-0700
```

And they seem to correspond to:

- `1184050800000` - Unix timestamp in milliseconds
- `-0700` - this would be the timezone offset UTC-07:00

You could parse it (I assume it's a string from a JSON object) and convert it to a `DateTime` like this:

```
string dateString = "/Date(1184050800000-0700)/";
Regex re = new Regex(@"(\d+)([-+]\d{4})");
Match match = re.Match(dateString);

long timestamp = Convert.ToInt64(match.Groups[1].Value);
int offset = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups[2].Value) / 100;

DateTime date = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddMilliseconds(timestamp).AddHours(-offset);
Console.WriteLine(date); // 7/10/2007 2:00:00 PM
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the full solution that OP is looking for. :)

Answer (score 0):

Am I wrong? It looks like a regexp to me, not a date object at all.

Answer (score -1):

```
DateTime now = new DateTime(1184050800000);
Console.WriteLine(now); // 2/01/0001 8:53:25 AM
```

Could this be correct if you aren't interested in the year?

Comment: I've never used that DateTime constructor before - cool! However, it seems that the parameter means: `A date and time expressed in the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since January 1, 0001 at 00:00:00.000 in the Gregorian calendar.` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2xf7zzk.aspx) Thus, I don't think that this is the correct approach.