# how convert 1606813200000 to 2020-12-01T09:00:00.000Z with c#

Tags: c#, datetime

can not convert date The following object to datetime in c#

```
{"date":1606813200000 , "open":119000.0, "high":130900.0, "low":107500.0, "close":113300.0, "volume":36892044.0}
```

I do not understand the relationship between the two

Why `1606813200000 == 2020-12-01T09:00:00.000Z`?

can you cee , ralationship to site https://jsoneditoronline.org/

Comment: `string isoDate = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(1606813200000).ToString("o");`?

Comment: `1606813200000` is the time in milliseconds between `1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z` (the "unix epoch") and `2020-12-01T09:00:00.000Z`. You can see this by entering it [here](https://www.epochconverter.com/).

Comment: Does this answer your question [Convert epoch/unix to Datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15926261/convert-epoch-unix-to-datetime) and [C# Epoch time to date and timezone convertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29862301/c-sharp-epoch-time-to-date-and-timezone-convertion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number you see is a Javascript timestamp ([number of milliseconds elapsed since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now)). You can test it in any browser console:

[image]

Following [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687357/how-to-convert-javascript-numeric-date-into-c-sharp-date-using-c-not-javascri), you can convert back to `DateTime` object:

```
public static DateTime ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(double timestamp)
{
    DateTime origin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    return origin.AddSeconds(timestamp / 1000); // convert from milliseconds to seconds
}
```

From the comment, I realize there is this method [DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.fromunixtimemilliseconds?view=net-5.0) as well:

```
// Convert Timestampt to DateTimeOffset
var time = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(1606813200000);

// Convert back to ISO string
var isoString = time.ToString("o");
```